# What function or JS library do I need to make info box appear when mousing over a map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps JS API v3 uses `InfoWindow`, which appears when the user clicks a marker on the map. I would like instead for info to appear in a box next to the mouse arrow when a user mouses over a marker or other objects on a GMap object.

In the end, I would like it look something like [this example](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2014/01/05/poverty-map/). Click on a city at the bottom and mouse over the polygons. You'll see an infobox appear where your mouse is. Does GMaps API have something like this built in? Do I need to write up a custom function? Or has someone made a JS library that does what I'm requesting?

If Google Maps API had a dedicated forum or Google Group to post this question, I would post it there. [But Google's own documentation states that support questions should go to Stack Overflow](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vohijus/11/edit?js,output). You can click on the map to create markers. When you hover over a marker, an info window opens up. When you move the cursor away from the marker, the info window closes.

The main section of the code that adds this functionality is the `setMarkerListeners` function. Its body is:

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(marker.position.toString()); // Set desired info window content
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
});
```

I believe the code is pretty self-explanatory.

As for customizing the info window, the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#customize) say "The InfoWindow class does not offer customization."

However, it looks like there *are* some resources online for dealing with this. Take a look at the [snazzy-info-window plugin](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window) or [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/xboPmG). Hopefully those help. :)